# Mappolyline in WP8 from XAML does not work?

Tags: windows-phone-8

all  I am working with WP 8 new Maps from Nokia.
Having a bit problem with mappolyline from xaml, it won't show.
Tried (Some init code removed): 
Where Coords is just a public property of type GeoCoordinateCollection
I can show the polygon by doing code but that's not what I want now when I have learned about binding code to templates and so on.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="Map" Grid.Row="1"  >
        <maps:Map.MapElements >
            <maps:MapPolyline StrokeColor="red" StrokeThickness="2" Path="{Binding Coords}"></maps:MapPolyline>
        </maps:Map.MapElements>
</maps:Map>
```

Comment: This answer may be related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408379/mapoverlay-binding-not-working

Comment: I can confirm this problem happens with programatic creation too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625797/mappolyline-not-being-drawn

Answer (score 0):

Try adding polyline through code,

```
    var _polyline = new MapPolyline();
    line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
    line.StrokeThickness = 2;
    line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(lat,long));
    line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(lat, long));
    MyMap.MapElements.Add(line);
```

Comment: this should be comment, since it does not provide answer to the question.