# MapPolyline not being drawn

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use a MapPolyLine in my Map to show a real-time route, hopefully it will move/scale [this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607184/transform-path-polyline-corresponding-to-map-zoom-move-action). The thing is the line is not being shown on the map, and I cannot find any programming mistake:

C#

```
MapLayer pathLayer;

//Constructor
 pathLayer = new MapLayer();
 MapPolyline line = new MapPolyline();
 line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
 line.StrokeThickness = 10;
 //line.Path.Add(several points); Tested, no effect
 MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay();
 overlay.Content = line;
 //overlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(0,0); Tested, no effect
 //overlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0); Tested, no effect
 pathLayer.Add(overlay);
 MyMap.Layers.Add(pathLayer);


void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  MapPolyline line = pathLayer.First(TrackPath).Content as MapPolyline;
  line.Path.Add(args.Position.Coordinate); // Checked values, line.Path adds them correctly
}
```

EDIT: New info. The emulator shows an error when trying to add it using XAML, and the emulator shows the name of the class on the top of the map as a graphic glitch:

[image: Emulator error on top, XAML on the right]

Comment: I also see the XAML error but it is still building and the polyline is showing up when I define the path in XAML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MapPolylines` and `MapPolygons` should be added to the `MapElements` collection... not a `MapLayer` or a `MapOverlay`.

You should be able to make this example work for you.

```
        MapPolyline line = new MapPolyline();
        line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        line.StrokeThickness = 10;
        line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(47.6602, -122.098358));
        line.Path.Add(new GeoCoordinate(47.561482, -122.071544));
        MyMap.MapElements.Add(line);
```

In your GeoCoord watcher you'll have to get the line from the map's `MapElements` collection, and add the new position to the line's path instead of predefining like I did. This should be doable.

Comment: Noticed you've answered a few questions on wp8 and I was wondering if you could out this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830053/windows-phone-8-gps-altitude-problems/13834473

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1 try add points in this way. "punkty" is my collection.

```cs
  List<BasicGeoposition> PosList = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
  foreach (var item in punkty)
  {
    PosList.Add(new BasicGeoposition()
    {
      Latitude = item.Position.Latitude,
      Longitude = item.Position.Longitude
    });
  }

  //Example of one point
  //PosList.Add(new BasicGeoposition()
  //{
  //  Latitude = 52.46479093,
  //  Longitude = 16.91743341
  //});

  MapPolyline line = new MapPolyline();
  line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
  line.StrokeThickness = 5;
  line.Path = new Geopath(PosList);

  myMap.MapElements.Add(line);
```