# How are we supposed to draw polylines on Here maps with Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, polyline

I'm trying to draw a polyline on Here Maps, and can't find any tutorial or decent documentation on that subject.

Here's what I've been doing up to now.

I create my map directly in the view:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Loaded="HereMap_Loaded"/>
```

When the map is available, it calls this code:

```
private void HereMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    initData();

    map2.Center = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0);
    map2.ZoomLevel = 13;
    map2.LandmarksEnabled = true; //Shows 3D buildings when available.

    draw();
}
```

The call to draw does this:

```
public void draw()
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline polyline = this.createPolylineFromArray(arrayOfGeoCoordinates);

    polyline.StrokeThickness = 12;
    polyline.StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 189, 179, 217);

    MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay
    {
        Content = polyline
    };

    Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer layer = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer();
    layer.Add(overlay);
    map2.Layers.Add(layer);
}
```

And I create my polyline from a list of GeoCoordinates:

```
public Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline createPolylineFromArray(List<GeoCoordinate> pArray)
{
    if (pArray.Capacity > 1) {
        GeoCoordinateCollection path = new GeoCoordinateCollection();

        foreach (GeoCoordinate coordinate in pArray)
        {
            path.Add(coordinate);
        }

        Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline polyline = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapPolyline
        {
            Path = path
        };

        return polyline;
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Now, I tried to create a circle overlay instead of a polyline before, and it worked.
I've done it this way:

```
Content = new Ellipse
{
    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    Width = 40, 
    Height = 40
}
```

When I replaced the circle overlay with the polyline as shown above, it displays the following picture:

[image: Polyline error]

You perfectly see the map, and the overlay appears as a texte line at the upper edge of the screen, displaying the overlay class package name.

What am I missing? I'm expecting it to display a polyline that will follow the map movements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MapPolyline not being drawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625797/mappolyline-not-being-drawn)

Comment: You're right, I thought Here Maps and Bing Maps worked differently. This solved my problem, thank you.