# Binding map overlays to a collection in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently developing an app for Windows Phone 8 and I encounter some issues due to the asynchronism of all network operations.

I have a list of GeoCoordinate items that I retrieve from an XML file stored on my own website.
These points represent a path that I would like to display on a map.

This list can easily be changed into a list of MapOverlay objects.
However, using

```
map.Layers.Add(...);
```

does not help as the list is not built at the moment of the call (the XML loading and reading is asynchronous).

After having a look at the documentation, it looks like a single MapOverlay XAML item can be easily binded to a GeoCoordinate object.
However, I could not find any way to bind a MapLayer XAML item to a collection of GeoCoordinate objects which, I think, would make sense... All the solutions I found on the Internet were only usable for Windows Phone 7.

If anyone has an idea, I would be glad to hear it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to add the overlay through code.
Using events, it is very easy to do and not so ugly.
For those interested in events, this tutorial might be useful: [MSDN Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: More light on how you managed to solve this would really help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to the same question about XAML MapOverlay collection binding at @ [MapOverlay binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408379/mapoverlay-binding-not-working/13429841#13429841)

Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: I already had a look at your post while looking for a solution earlier. If I understand it well, it only works for a single overlay (one GeoCoordinate object) while I am trying to draw a complete path on the map. :/

Comment: Just thinking that a workaround may be to draw a polygon from my GeoCoordinate and add it to the map. Only one object to manage => easier data binding.